# How to color each movieclip in a row

Tags: actionscript-3

I will apreciate your help. I have 8 movieclips (square1-8) and a movieclip called plus1 on stage to handle the 8 movieclips. I want to click plus1 once and color square1, press plus1 for the second time and color square2 and so on. This is my code but it seems that there is something wrong because it color random. Can you please help me find what's wrong with it?

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;


plus1.buttonMode=true;
var sximata:MovieClip = square1;
var myColorTransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();


plus1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeColour);

function changeColour(event:MouseEvent):void
{
if (contains(square1))
{
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare1);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare16);
        }
if (contains(square2))
{
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare2);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare3);
}
if (contains(square3))
{
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare3);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare4);
}
if (contains(square4))
{
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare4);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare5);
}
if (contains(square5))
{
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare5);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare6);
}
if (contains(square6))
{
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare6);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare7);
}
if (contains(square7))
{
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare7);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare8);
}

myColorTransform.color = 0xBDB522;

      sximata.transform.colorTransform = myColorTransform;

}



square1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare1);
function onsquare1(e:MouseEvent):void {
sximata = square1;
}


square2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare2);
function onsquare2(e:MouseEvent):void {
sximata = square2;
}

square3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare3);
function onsquare3(e:MouseEvent):void {
sximata = square3;
}


 square4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare4);
 function onsquare4(e:MouseEvent):void {
sximata = square4;
}


  square5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare5);
  function onsquare5(e:MouseEvent):void {
sximata = square5;
}

 square6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare6);
function onsquare6(e:MouseEvent):void {
sximata = square6;
}

square7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare7);
function onsquare7(e:MouseEvent):void {
sximata = square7;
}


square8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onsquare8);
function onsquare8(e:MouseEvent):void {
sximata = square8;
}
```

OK. My code looks like this now

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;


plus1.buttonMode=true;
minus1.buttonMode=true;


var nextSquare:MovieClip = square1;

var squares:Array = [square1, square2, square3, square4, square5, square6, square7, square8];

var myColorTransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();


plus1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeColour);

function changeColour(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    myColorTransform.color = 0x519596;
    nextSquare.transform.colorTransform = myColorTransform;

    var index = squares.indexOf(nextSquare);
    if (index < squares.length - 1) {
        nextSquare = squares[index + 1];
     } else {
        trace('we are done');
    }   
}

minus1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reversecolour);

function reversecolour(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    nextSquare.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform();
    var index = squares.indexOf(nextSquare);
    if (index < squares.length - 1) {
        nextSquare = squares[index - 1];
    } else {
        trace('we are done');
      }   
   }
```

But i get this error

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at _fla::MainTimeline/changeColour()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need so many event handlers. Can't you just keep the squares in an array and each time `plus1` is clicked color and move to the next? Check out the code below.

```
plus1.buttonMode=true;

var nextSquare:MovieClip = square1;

var squares:Array = [square1, square2, square3, square4, square5, square6, square7, square8];

var myColorTransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();

plus1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeColour);

function changeColour(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    myColorTransform.color = 0xBDB522;
    nextSquare.transform.colorTransform = myColorTransform;

    var index = squares.indexOf(nextSquare);
    if (index < squares.length - 1) {
        nextSquare = squares[index + 1];
    } else {
        trace('we are done');
    }   
}
```

Comment: What if i want to keep a track of the movieclips that have already been colored? Lets say that square 1-5 are colored, i do something else on stage and i continue to color the rest of them (square6-8). How can i do that?

Comment: This already handles that, since the last colored movieclip is stored in nextSquare. The next time you click plus1 it will color the next square in the array.

Comment: Yes you are right. I did not express my self correctly. I am planning to put another movieclip to do the opposite  but I have a difficulty to tell in actionscript to start to take movieclips from the last colored movieclip and go back. I will appreciate if you can give my some guidance. Thank you.

Comment: Just add the new movie clip and when it is clicked instead of doing `nextSquare = squares[index + 1]` go in reverse with `nextSquare = squares[index - 1]` and remove coloring.

Comment: I did it (you can see it above) but i have an error (I wrote it above) and it start to go back in its original colour in the second click.

Comment: You need to modify the if statement too to make sure you don't try to access negative indices. If index is 0 then `index - 1` will give that error.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I change it so now it says if (index > 0) {
        nextSquare = squares[index - 1]; but it seems that i am not doing it right because minus1 starts after the second click.